# HTML Table Hover Zoom (like jqZoom, but for Tables)

Tags: javascript, html, zooming

I'm seeking a twist on the typical image zoom.  I have a large grid (HTML table), which I want to present the equivalent of a thumbnail of (it would be readable, but pretty small).  I'd like to create a small draggable panning window (say, 6x6 table cells) where the mouse cursor is, and then in a nearby zoom viewport, I'd like to display a larger version of the cells that are under my mouse's draggable pan window.

The effect would be similar to this image zoom plugin:

[jqZoom](http://www.mind-projects.it/projects/jqzoom/demos.php)

I've seen tons of these things for image zooming, but not for table (or basic text) zooming.

I'm a first-time poster, but I've been around enough to have read all of the "what have you tried" and "Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine" articles.  In this case, I haven't tried anything because I'm hoping there's a tool out there that can do this for me.  I just can't find it.

Anyone know of a plugin or some code that'll achieve this effect for tables?

Here's a fiddle to start with, but as stated in the comments, I haven't done much more than create a grid and a target div:

http://jsfiddle.net/UFyPs/2/

Comment: Could we see your `table` html? And how it fits into your page? Where would the zoomed `table` be presented?

Comment: @DavidThomas, this is purely experimental now to see if I can achieve the effect.  If I create a fiddle for it, it's literally going to be a 20x20 table with a `div` next to it for "viewport".  But I'm happy to do that.  I'm a decent JS developer, but I literally don't know where to begin with this, and I've never even seen it in the wild.

Comment: @DavidThomas, I added a starter Fiddle, which I should have done from the get-go.